# How to get timing when querying with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, shell, t-sql

I'm testing Microsoft SQL Server, I want to check that how much time it takes when I perform a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query window place SQL like below:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;  

--Your Query Goes Here 
SELECT * FROM Table

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @startDate datetime
Declare @endDate datetime
begin

set @startDate=GETDATE()
select * from Table1
set @endDate=GETDATE()
 select DATEDIFF(ms,@startDate,@endDate) as 'Execution Time '


     /*
 ms is for millisecond you can also use following argument
 minute mi, n
second  ss, s
millisecond ms
microsecond mcs
nanosecond  ns
 */
 end
```

Comment: better approach @ hitesh

Comment: @SunnyJangid - No it isn't. It doesn't give you the breakdown of CPU and elapsed time and compile time and would also involve littering your code with timing statements that you then need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @EndT datetime
DECLARE @StartT datetime 
SELECT @StartT=GETDATE() 

-- Write Your Query


SELECT @EndT=GETDATE()

--This will return execution time of your query
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartT,EndT) AS [Execution Time in millisecs]
```

for more information About DATEDIFF See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql